# I'm trying to make an image a button, using python tkinter. However, the image button only shows up when I put a character on the line below

Tags: python, image, tkinter, button

I have created an image as a button. Upon opening a pop put window, I want the image button to be in a specific place (I've used the grid method). However, the button only appears when I include a character (any character) in the line below the button code.
When the character is included, the image appears and the function called by the pressing of it works perfectly. I do get an error message when the pop out window initially appears though.

Here is my code:

```
def eastereggtxt1():
    function works fine so don't worry about this 
    function

img = PhotoImage(file = r'pathtoimage.png')

imgbutn = Button(EntryWindow,
image = img, borderwidth = 0,
command = eastereggtxt1)
imgbutn.grid(row = 18, column = 7)

r
```

The image/button only shows up if I run it with the above character "r" included. However, the character can be any letter really. without it, the image doesn't show up.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you mean the 'r' immediately preceding the file path?  That 'r' denotes that the path is a raw string which among other things means you do not have to escape any backslashes, which you would otherwise need to do in a regular string.  You should consider using os.path to keep your code independent of the OS.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: I have a guess that you image always shows up but you only see it when there is a letter at the end because it will raise an error and stop your program. Probably your code are losing the reference for the image somewhere. Try to make `img` a global variable

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for this code to run at all. You're missing import statements, and you haven't created a root window or called `mainloop`. Please provide a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Try removing ```r``` from the image path. Also, it'd be good if ```function works fine so don't......``` would be a comment instead of the code.

Comment: Holy heck!!! making img global was the key. Thank you all for your help and comments.

Comment: That really doesn't make any sense to me. Could you explain what was the problem and how making `img` global solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code is this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()

def eastereggtxt1():
    print("Easter Eggs!")

image = PhotoImage(file = r'easter_eggs.png') # I use easter_eggs as an example

image_button = Button(root, image = image, command = eastereggtxt1)
image_button.grid(row = 18, column = 7)
mainloop() # I just know that you can just do mainloop(), but it's not effective
```

I tryed the code, it works fine, but when I try to replace `r` with something else, (Example: l,p,s), an error occured:

```
PS C:\Users\user#1> python -u "D:\Test\test1.py"
  File "D:\Test\test1.py", line 9
    img = PhotoImage(file = s'easter_eggs')
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It refers that the code can't use any other character than `r`.

Also you mentioned:

> The image/button only shows up if I run it with the above character "r" included.

I think your OS doesn't support without the character `r`? If this is wrong, please  tell me in the comments.

Peace :D

Comment: Kevin, thank you for your response. Sorry for the confusion, I shouldn't have used the 'r' character for the example. I was not referring to the 'r' in the: image = PhotoImage(file = r'easter_eggs.png') line. That definitely has to be 'r'. What I was saying was that the images don't appear unless I have a character included under the button code, that is why there is that strange looking 'r' floating under the:  'imgbutn = Button(EntryWindow,
image = img, borderwidth = 0,
command = eastereggtxt1)
imgbutn.grid(row = 18, column = 7)' code. that character can be any character such as 'h', 'p'

Comment: However, that floating character has to be there for the images to appear. Even though this causes an error to in my terminal, when that character is included, the image/buttons appear and work perfectly. I can't figure out why the image/buttons don't appear without that character...

Comment: @EstebanLoetz That's weird, it should've raised an `error` because you are putting in characters that shouldn't be there in the `last line`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a label instead of a button. That could be a good option.
But you'll need to change a few lines of code.

In the `eastereggtext1()` function, pass an argument `event`.
Example:

```
def eastereggtext(event):
    # function code here...
```

Then, remove the button and add an image.

```
imgbutn = Label(root, image=img)
imgbutn.grid(row = 18, column = 7)
```

Then, bind the label to mouse click.

```
imgbutn.bind("<Button-1>", eastereggtext1)
```

For more info about tkinter bindings: [Python | Binding function in Tkinter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-binding-function-in-tkinter/)

So here's the full code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, PhotoImage
# other modules you need to import

root = Tk()
root.title("Title of the window")

def eastereggtext1(event):
    # function code here....

img = PhotoImage(file = 'image_path.png')

imgbutn = Label(root, image=img)
imgbutn.grid(row = 18, column = 7)
imgbutn.bind("<Button-1>", eastereggtext1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ishaan, your code modification works. However, it behaves exactly like my button code. The images don't appear unless I include that strange floating character below the button code in my above example. In the example I used the character 'r' but it can be any character such as 'p', 'u', 'm'... Not sure if it makes a difference, but the window that I have these images appearing in is a pop out window so the imgbutn = Label(root, image = img) line really looks like imgbutn = Label(EntryWindow, image = img) in my code. I wanted to simplify my example as much as possible though.

Comment: @EstebanLoetz, it's good that you tried to simplify your code as much as possible. However, it should still be complete. Could you update your question with a [mre]? So can you reproduce the problem without using `EntryWindow`? Or could you otherwise it in your code? That way, we can reproduce the problem too and help finding a correct answer.

Comment: @EstebanLoetz does this happen to all images? Or just the one you are using?